# GitLab CI building VueJs to deploy to S3 fails with Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm getting the following error when my below CI script tries to build my VueJs app:

```
$ npm run build
> cient-name@0.1.0 build /builds/client-name/client-name-project
> vue-cli-service build
-  Building for production...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'
Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader-v16/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at api.chainWebpack.webpackConfig (/builds/client-name/client-name-project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js:114:23)
    at webpackChainFns.forEach.fn (/builds/client-name/client-name-project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:40)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/builds/client-name/client-name-project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:26)
    at PluginAPI.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/builds/client-name/client-name-projectd/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/PluginAPI.js:145:25)
    at module.exports (/builds/client-name/client-name-project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/resolveAppConfig.js:9:22)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

The full CI script is here:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build prod:
  image: node:10.15.0-stretch
  stage: build
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    # Install vuecli
    - npm install -g @vue/cli@latest
    # Install dependencies
    - npm install
    # Build App
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      # Build folder
      - dist/
    expire_in: 1 hour

deploy prod:
  image: python:latest
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - pip install awscli
    - aws s3 sync ./dist bucket-name
```

The pipeline successfully runs past `npm install -g @vue/cli@latest`, then `npm install`, but fails on the final `npm build` step.

Comment: I'm sure you've already tried this, but if you add `npm list` above `npm run build` is `vue-loader-v16` in the output?